# Using Java annotation to generate serialization code?

Tags: java, annotations

Serialization is a lot of boilerplate. I was wondering if I could use annotations to write that for me, thus allowing the structure of the object to double as its on-disk format.

I know Jackson exists but ObjectMapper feels too magical and I'd like to just have something like this:

```
@SynthSerializer
public class Foo {
    public final String name;
    public final String description;

    public Foo(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
//Following code generated at compile time by @SynthSerializer:
public class FooSerializer: implements Serializable {
    //Boilerplate, you know the drill
}
```

Incidentally, from what I understand modifying source code using annotations is a hack, but creating altogether new classes (like in my example) is an intended use case for annotations. That's true, yes?

Anyway, is this kind of generation possible with annotations? Is this a sane way to do something like this? And do annotation processors that already do something like this exist?

Comment: I think this is kind of "too broad". And I am not getting your point: A) do you want to invent your own serialization format (if so: why?) B) the whole point of frameworks such as Jackson or Gson is (more or less) work out of the box. I really fail to see the problem that you intend to solve here?

Comment: You are attempting to reinvent the wheel.  Consider using actual java serialization, which is built in and tested.

Comment: No, I'd use JSON and Serializable in an actual implementation. The MySerializer thing is just for conciseness in the example. As for the problem I'm trying to solve, I mainly want to practice annotations. This isn't for production code.

Comment: I edited the code to show I intend to use Serializable.

Comment: That seems possible, although I'm not sure that I really understand your example. (Why does `FooSerializer` implement `Serializable`?) You might see this blog series if you want to learn code generation with annotations: https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/annotation-types/ Whether it's sane or not seems kind of hard to speculate about. That would probably depend more on the specific end result of the API design. I think it's more typical for this kind of thing to be done with reflection.

Comment: Reflection is typically the way to go, but not all targets support it.